# Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 - Keyboard Shortcut is Not Working

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, rename, visual-studio-express

In Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012, the rename shortcut is not working.

I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>.

What else should I try?

Here are my shortcut settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems that F2 is only mapped to the Rename command when in the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools and Table Designer contexts.

- Open your keyboard shortcuts
- Find **Refactor.Rename**
- Under **Use new shortcut in**, select  **Text Editor**
- Under **Press shortcut keys**, press the shortcut, e.g. <kbd>F2</kbd>
- Click Assign

This will allow you to use the keyboard shortcut in the correct context.